# JEditorPane and content width

Tags: java, html, swing, width, jeditorpane

I have some code where I take some text in html format, put it in a JEditorPane and create an image from it, as below:

```
String text = getMyText();
int height = getContentHeight(text);
int width = 850;

image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();
graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);

JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
jep.putClientProperty(JEditorPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, Boolean.TRUE);
jep.setContentType("text/html");
jep.setFont(new Font(myFont));

jep.setSize(width, height);
jep.setText(text);
jep.print(graphics);

graphics.dispose();

String fileName = "myFileName" + ".extension";

File outputfile = new File(myPath + "/" + fileName );

ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
```

This works wonderfully until the point I have some element in my html text with some fixed width (i.e. a div, or a table etc)

Since my original width is fixed at 850 pixels, if the width of that element is greater than that, what is happening is that the image looks like is being cut, meaning you cannot read certain text.

Is there a way so the text won't go over my fixed width? Or is it just a matter of making sure the width is within the limits beforehand?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you mean you want to Word wrap the text displayed on top of the image? I think you have to use a textArea to do this, it has a word wrap function.

Comment: Kinda, even though it word wraps correctly the rest of the test!

Comment: Would help to show some reproducible code... but have you tried wrapping the `JEditorPane` in a `JScrollPane` and instead of calling `setSize` on the `JEditorPane` override `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` of the `JScrollPane` to set your initial size i.e. 850